# Warnings: "The following classpath entry <address> will not be available on the server's classpath"

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I'm fairly new to Java, having completed only most of an intro to programming course, and am trying to learn by doing at this point. After I've set up my libgdx project and imported it, I get these two warnings, both saying:

"The following classpath entry  will not be available on the server's classpath"

I need two answers on this. Firstly, why does this error come up? What does it mean? Second, how do I fix it?

Comment: You might want to give us some more context on your problem. You're trying to make a server based game? Where/how did you try to install libgdx? With what little information you've provided, I can only take a wild guess and say that your server has a WEB-INF directory, within which should be a lib directory where libgdx should be. More info, however, gets you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when using the libgdx setup gui, you probably generated a HTML5/GWT project as well. This one works a bit different. You will have a server where your application will be deployed to. This webserver will have its own libraries and its own classpath.

The error message basically tells you, that a certain dependency will not be available on the server. In your GWT project there should be a configuration file named GwtDefinition.gwt.xml where you can define additional dependencies.

I don't know what `<address>` is, but you probably need to configure your GwtDefinition correctly.

If you do not care about the HTML5/Browser version for now, you can also just ignore the warning and try if everything works with the desktop mode.

Comment: Thank you. For right now, I'm just worried about learning how to use libgdx in general. I can worry about making my html5 copy function when I actually want to make a game with a web version.